# Point-point communication using Java Message Service (JMS)

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I have a simple question that I can't find an answer to. 
I know that a publisher and a subscriber have no connection to each other but how about queues? For a point-point communication, does the message producer have to establish a connection to the message consumer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the message producer have to establish a connection to the message consumer?

No - the producer passes the message to the JMS server (which acts as a store and forward device).  The JMS server will pass the message on to the consumer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer!